# Uncommon (Unorthodox?!) Pinyin: What are these?

Tags: pinyin

I find this sort of uncommon, unorthodox, whatever you wanna call it, pinyin very fascinating. These are the ones that I know of already - that, apparently, are still considered to be Mandarin. What I'm wondering is, are there others? What other wild, bizarre pinyin(s) exist in Mandarin and what characters go along with them?

·cěi

·cèi

## 覅

·fiào

## 黁

·nún

[image: biang]

·biāng

Comment: fiao is absolutely dialectal (Wu dialect).

Comment: Sure but 中华字海 p.1184 has it listed as fiào - mandarin enough for me!

Comment: @user3306536 No, it includes many dialectal characters, as well as rare, strange, obsolete, even non-Chinese characters...

Comment: These are very rare words，we don't use them in daily life.We always replace them with synonyms.They are all dialect words.We will use the dialect in the daily life and others.

Comment: In fact there are too many. For some words, we just say them but never write them, especially in some dialects. And maybe no one knows how to write them correctly. Those characters, if written, usually have uncommon pronunciation. If you try to learn a dialect, you'll find a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so far,

> nóu   羺
>
> yō    哟
>
> nòu   耨   搙   槈   檽   獳   鎒   鐞

Answer (score 5):

I think I know one.

扥
dèn

This means "pull with a little brutal force".

Answer (score 5):

Skimmed through the [Pinyin index page of 汉典](http://www.zdic.net/z/pyjs/), and found that, as user58955 commented, most of the uncommon pinyin included there were either dialectal or obsolete, as a native speaker, I have never come across them in my life in either spoken or written mandarin.

I did find one that can still be heard in nowadays spoken mandarin but I guess most Chinese do not know how to write. That is an onomatopoeia: 欻(chuā) as in "欻的一声"

You may also like to know 嗲(diǎ), which means coquettish, although it may not sound that uncommon to native speakers.